# Why my shell script not working with cron?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have two shell scripts .

(**working one**)

```
$ cat script_nas.sh

#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat nas_filers`
do echo $i
  touch /mnt/config-backup/nas_backup/$i.auditlog.0.$(date '+%Y%m%d')
  ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 root@$i rdfile /etc/configs/config_saved > /mnt/config-backup/nas_backup/$i.auditlog.0.$(date '+%Y%m%d')
done
```

other

(**not working one**)

```
$ cat script_san.sh

#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat san_filers`
do echo $i
  touch /mnt/config-backup/san_backup/$i.auditlog.0.$(date '+%Y%m%d')
  ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 root@$i rdfile /etc/configs/config_saved > /mnt/config-backup/san_backup/$i.auditlog.0.$(date '+%Y%m%d')
done
```

Cron entries are:

```
$ crontab -l
Filers config save script
0 0 * * * /mnt/config-backup/script_san.sh
0 0 * * * /mnt/config-backup/script_nas.sh
0 0 * * * /mnt/config-backup/delete_file
```

Script script_san.sh is not working. 
Outputs are like 
SAN backup directory

```
san_backup]# ls -lart alln01-na-exch01a.cisco.com.auditlog*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 210083 Mar  1 22:24 alln01-na-exch01a.auditlog.0.20150301
[root@XXXXX san_backup]# pwd
/mnt/config-backup/san_backup
```

NAS backup directory

```
nas_backup]# ls -lart rcdn9-25f-filer43b.cisco.com.auditlog*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 278730 Feb 26 00:06 rcdn9-25f-filer43b.cisco.com.auditlog.0.20150226
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 281612 Feb 27 00:17 rcdn9-25f-filer43b.cisco.com.auditlog.0.20150227
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284105 Feb 28 00:02 rcdn9-25f-filer43b.cisco.com.auditlog.0.20150228
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284101 Mar  1 00:02 rcdn9-25f-filer43b.cisco.com.auditlog.0.20150301
[root@XXXXXXX nas_backup]#
```

From cron logs I can see that cron is executing both the script but output for `script_san.sh` is not coming.

Comment: Add `-x` parameter in the 1st line  to your non-working script to see if you'll get any output at all. E.g. `#!/bin/bash -x` and add `-v` for your `ssh` to debug it. Does it work when you run it manually the same way as it's in cron?

Comment: check the "debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info There are some solutions to recurring problems.

Comment: Yes, when I run it manually it works fine and create all backup files. But working only manually not at the schedule time. As per cron logs script is running.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, most of the times script is working manually but not from crontab is because login scripts were not running. Try to add something like `source ~/.bash_profile` in the begging of script or first line in cron file. Did you try (for debugging) to run the script with `at` command?